# When all Borel subsets of a Borel set B have measure 0 for signed $\mu$, prove within Bourbaki MT that B has measure 0 for $|\mu|$ (total variation)

Tags: measure-theory, compactness, borel-sets

Suppose X is a locally compact space and $\mu$ a *bounded* and *regular* signed measure defined on the Borel sets of X, $B$ one of these sets. Prove that if $\mu(B_1)=0$ for all Borel sets $B_1$ contained in $B$, then $|\mu|(B)=0$.

**Motivation**: Rudin's Functional Analysis, chapter on bounded operators in Hilbert spaces. I found that I needed the result above (which I hope is true!) with *complex* measures to confirm the validity of the proof of the first non trivial theorem about resolutions of the identity (12.21 in my edition) ... and I was able to deduce that complex case from the real (signed) case

(Bounded regular measures are those that are associated with linear maps from the space of continuous complex-valued functions with compact support defined in X to $\mathbb C$ that are continuous with respect to the sup-norm on said space.)

Comment: What I mention about Hilbert spaces doesn't mean that you need to know anything about them or operator theory to answer my question. Therefore tags on Hilbert or operators are not included

Comment: Do you mean $|\mu|(B)=0$? Is so the answer is clearly contained in Rudin's book. See the chapter on complex measures.

Comment: Yes and I corrected my question. Are you talking about Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis? I had it once in rent from the local library in tech high school for some other topic

Comment: Follows directly from the definition of variation: for any measurable set $A$, $|\mu|(A)=\sup\{\sum_n|\mu(E_n)|\}$ where the supreme is taken over all measurable partitions $\{E_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of $A$.

Comment: Yes I see that also in Wikipedia, with *that* definition it follows indeed easily from the def. But I am using Bourbaki measure theory, where there is another definition of $|\mu|$ - because the two def. are probably equivalent in my case, this tells me, it has good chance to be true also in my setting ... some proofs go the same independently of which measure theory is used, which I hoped. I have written down a set of simple properties of total var. which are the only ones used by Bourbaki as far as I saw. A proof using only these would satisfy my needs

Comment: Following for last comment: is there interest for copying here said list of properties?

Comment: What is the definition of $|\mu|$ in Bourbaki's book?

Comment: Not sure showing here Bourbaki's def. of $|\mu|$ will help much. I offered to list instead simple *properties* of this abs. val. of a measure that 1)seem to suffice for its use (Bourbaki never uses again his def. after giving them) 2)work the same for both measure theories. Like that someone might - by using these properties instead of a def. - find a proof (using the intuitions he associates with measures) that would work for me too. To understand Bourbaki's def. it is necessary to understand that Bourbaki's theory uses also another idea of what measures are formally

Comment: (last comm. cont'ed) In Rudin and others, a measure on a *set* X is a map defined on a part M of the power set of X with real or complex values, where M and the map have to fulfill some conditions. In Bourbaki, may-be based on a concept of Laurent Schwartz, a measure on a *locally compact top. space* X is a continuous linear map defined on the vector space V of complex-valued continuous functions with domain X and compact support and scalar (complex) values, V being topologized in a certai manner which I won't mention - i.e. said measures are the elements of the topological dual space of V

Comment: The 2 measure theories allow the same sorts of things - except where 1 of them behaves "badly" . If you start with a measure defined on subsets of X, you use it to define the integrals of (very) general functions defined on X. If you start with a linear map as said, that means you 'know' already the integral of those special functions and one can then prolongate the integral to very general functions - by continuity with respect to the topology of convergence in the mean which is defined as part of the process. One uses then the integral of indicator functions to get the measures of sets

Comment: Now back to total variation alias absolute value. Let $\mu$ be a measure defined as a linear contin' map V -> $\mathbb C$. Its total var. is defined on real positive elements $f$ of V by $|\mu|(f) = \sup|\mu(g)|$ where the supremum is on all functions $g$ in V such that $|g| \le f$. I gave this formula because someone asked for it. But you may forget it because it might not be really needed

Comment: Here are the properties of the abs. val. that seem to be the basics. $|\mu|$ is a positive (real) measure, $|\mu| = \mu$ if $\mu$ is already positive, $|\mu| = \mu^+ + \mu^-$ when $\mu$ is real (these measures with plus or minus are defined as in any ordered group that is a lattice - one proves that the real measures on X build such a group - & there are similar formulae for them (to the one given for $|\mu|$), which again are mainly used for this proof), $|\int f.d\mu| \le \int |f|.d|\mu|$ when $f$ is integrable for $\mu$ (or equivalently for $|\mu|$); finally $|\mu + \nu| \le |\mu| + |\nu|$

Comment: More than 3 weeks after I posted my question I finally was able to answer it myself. In the next days I will show what I found as an answer to my own question. First I intend to change the title because - contrary to my hope - no proof with classical measure theory (MT) was given, that works also for MT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is given for people comfortable with Bourbaki's theory of measure and integration - as shown in the chapters I to IV of his book "Integration". Others might not understand the following reasoning.

Important: although the same question could be asked and answered YES for (bounded) *complex* measures, I asked for real measures because it is relatively easy to deduce the complex case from the real one. And the following makes no sense for a complex measure.

To begin with, we'll use the theorem about the *Hahn decomposition* of a measure. The proof of this given by Halmos (and in a similar manner by other authors in classical MT) is valid practically without change in the linear MT, so I don't give details for that. I will use in the following the letters $A$ and $B$ for the two members of the Hahn decomposition of the given measure $\mu$, because that is what Halmos uses. The Borel set $B$ in the title of my Q. will be renamed here as $W$ to avoid confusion.

Now we will consider two measures on X, one with density $\phi_A$, the other  with density $\phi_B$ with respect to $\mu$, where $\phi_E:$ X->{0,1} is the characteristic function of a subset $E$ of X (having value 1 in $E$ and 0 elsewhere). We call these measures $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$. How is the measure $\nu$ with density $f$ with respect to $\mu$ defined (in Bourbaki's MT), $f$ being a bounded borelian function X->$\mathbb C$? It is such that $\int g d\nu = \int gf d\mu$ for all $g$ :X->$\mathbb C$ continuous with compact support. It is not too hard to deduce (in the Bourbaki framework) that this formula will hold for $g$ bounded borelian.

Applying this to characteristic functions for $f$ and $g$
we get that $\mu_A(C) = \mu(A \cap C)$ for a borelian set $C$ and similarly with $B$ instead of $A$. The choice of $A$ and $B$ as the positive and negative sets of the Hahn decomposition makes $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$ respectively a positive and a negative (bounded) measure. More precisely, they give set-measures to any Borel set C that are $\ge 0$ and $\le 0$ respectively, but a relatively easy argument lets deduce from this that $\mu_A \ge 0$ and $\mu_B \le 0$. Because $\phi_A + \phi_B$ is the constant function 1, an easily verified linearity property of the map $f \mapsto$ measure with density $f$ w.r.t. $\mu$ shows that $\mu_A + \mu_B = \mu$. Additivity of the measure of subsets and the special properties of $A$ and $B$ produced by the Hahn decomposition show that for a borelian set $C$ we have $\mu(C) \le \mu_A(C)$: one shows that this holds when $C \subset A$ and when $C \subset B$ and uses additivity for the general case. The argument mentioned for $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$ being $\ge 0$ and $\le 0$ respectively shows then (using it for a difference) that $\mu \le \mu_A$. Similarly we obtain $\mu_B \le \mu$ .

Now one defines (as in any group lattice): $\mu^+ = \sup(\mu,0)$ and $\mu^- = \sup(-\mu,0)$. As $\mu_A$ is $\ge$ 0 and $\ge \mu$, we have $\mu_A \ge \mu^+$. In the same way, one gets $-\mu_B \ge \mu^-$. From this, we deduce $\mu_A(C) \ge \mu^+(C)$ and $-\mu_B(C) \ge \mu^-(C)$ for a borelian set $C$... this step is not so trivial as it may seem (remember that in Bourbaki's MT a measure is a linear functional defined on continuous functions with compact support!).

Now we suppose that a borelian set $W$ has the property indicated in the result that is to be proved, and that $W_1$ is a borelian subset of $W$. We have $\mu^+(W_1) \le \mu_A(W_1) = \mu(A \cap W_1) = 0$; similarly $\mu^-(W_1) \le 0$. Because $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ are positive measures, we have in fact that $\mu^+(W_1)$ and $\mu^-(W_1)$ are zero. Here we may take $W_1 = W$; now $|\mu|$ is defined as in any group lattice to be $\mu^+ + \mu^-$. By linearity, $|\mu|(W) = 0$. (QED)